# Rounded corners on fieldset's and web standards

Tags: internet-explorer, css, cross-browser

I have seen a few questions bumping around about IE9 in specific.

IE9 now supports the `border-radius` property but won't apply it to a `fieldset`.

Note that Opera 11 behaves the same.

Where as Chrome, Firefox and Safari will all happily round the corners.

---

So what is the general consensus on:

**Rounding fieldset's is this a no go or is it something this browsers should be doing?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The spec doesn't explicitly state it, but sources around w3.org seem to indicate that `fieldsets` are to be styled with the `border-*` properties to customize the, well, borders.

The [HTML5 working draft](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/rendering.html#the-fieldset-element-0) suggests default styles for the `fieldset` element that browsers can use in their default styling implementations. You can see the `border` style in use here.

```
fieldset {
  margin-left: 2px; margin-right: 2px;
  border: groove 2px ThreeDFace;
  padding: 0.35em 0.625em 0.75em;
}
```

This would imply that there's a bug in IE and Opera which should be reported to Microsoft and Opera ASA respectively. I'm not too sure though as, again, W3C never said anything about `border-radius` (or `border-image`). You can always try filing bug reports and see what each vendor says.

**UPDATE:** as dstorey (an Opera employee) notes in a comment, this is a known bug in Opera.

Comment: Opera bugs can be reported at http://bugs.opera.com/wizard/ although this is a known issue CORE-35190 (CSS: border-radius ignored on fieldsets that have a legend)

Comment: Hopefully we’ll be able to fix it soon. It has a bunch of duplicate bugs so I'll inquire internally.